# Text letter by letter in GO

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing an unity game and I'd like to show text in a panel letter by letter (like if someone was typing).

I've already looked a few things (coroutines,IEnumerator) but didn't figure out how to do it.

My GO is a prefab that I instantiate.I don't instantiate in Scene window, all the instantiations are done in the code. And it't not a MonoBehaviour class.

This is the prefab I instantiate :

```
    InteractionIntro = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefab/Play/Interaction") as GameObject);
    InteractionIntro.transform.SetParent(canvasGameObject.transform, false);
    InteractionIntro.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 200, 0);
    public void SetInteractionText(string text)
    {
        InteractionIntro.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = text;
    }
```

The hierarchy looks like this :

[image]

So I'd like that the "Text" component has a letter-by-letter effect.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

@UPDATE : maybe adding a script to my prefab ?
@UPDATE : i read the text that's displayed from a file.

@EDIT : so i've created a script. Here's my code:

```
public class TypingEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject GO;   

    public float delay = 0.1f;
    public string fullText;
    private string currentText = "";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    }

    IEnumerator ShowText(){
        for(int i = 0; i <= fullText.Length; i++){
            currentText = fullText.Substring(0,i);
            GO.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

It works. Text is displayed letter by letter. But its a text I wrote on inspector:
[image]

How do I link text to the *setInteractionText* method ?

@UPDATE :  managed to do it, but it only writes letter-by-letter first text, if I display second text it does not work anymore. maybe reset ?

Comment: A coroutine would be a good idea, all it needs to do is execute every x seconds/milliseconds and copy the text value letter by letter to the component. You can index the string using a counter which increments each time the coroutine iterates. Hint: you can use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);` to defer continuation of the coroutine to wait for the next letter.

Comment: ok but how to I say in the script the text that has to be displayed letter by letter?

Comment: String indexing, keep a reference to the string you want to display (the whole thing) and iterate a counter each time the coroutine runs, indexing the string by the counter to get the next letter. Once you have a working version, update your answer, there are a few optimisations you can make but they aren't important unless performance is a factor.

Comment: E.g. `TheWholeString[counter]` will return a char that you can append to another string. Remember you only need to use the coroutine until you've printed all the letters, after that you can stop it.

Comment: @Charleh i've edited my question, could you check please ?

Comment: Looks good so far, if you can do that I'm sure you can figure out how to add another line/reset it... I'm not sure about the second part of the question as I don't really use unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a separate script.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TypingEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject GO;   

    public float delay = 0.05f;
    private string fullText;
    private string currentText = "";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }


    IEnumerator ShowText()
    {
        currentText="";


        for(int i = 0; i <= fullText.Length; i++){
            currentText = fullText.Substring(0,i);
            GO.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }


    }

    public void setText(string text)
    {
        this.fullText = text;
        StartCoroutine(ShowText());

    }
}
```

The method setText is called in another class every time I need to set another text. It's important to not forget to call StartCoroutine again.